# Reload material script

Tags: ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to update the texture of a plane to display the path of a mobile robot. I use openCV to modify a picture and add red squares on the robot path.

I managed to remove & re-include the "field" model using a world plugin, however the .material script is not reloaded during this operation. Thus I always have the same starting image and not the updated image.

Should I use the OGRE commands within my plugin or is there a way to reload the .material script using only the gazebo classes ?

So far what I am doing to delete/reload the model is (called every 1 sec, the new field has a new name):

> 

```
      // Delete old
      physics::ModelPtr m = this->world->GetModel(fieldName);
      m->Fini();

      // Add new
      t++;
      sprintf(fieldName,"field_%d", t);

      sdf::SDF soccerFieldSDF;
      std::string soccerField=
      "<sdf version ='1.4'>\
        <model name ='field'>\
          <static>true</static>\
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>\
          <link name='link'>\
                <visual name='visual'>\
                  <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>\
                  <geometry>\
                    <plane>\
                      <normal>0 0 1</normal>\
                      <size>120 90</size>\
                    </plane>\
                  </geometry>\
                  <material>\
                    <script>\
                       <uri>model://soccer_field/materials/scripts</uri>\
                       <uri>model://soccer_field/materials/textures</uri>\
                       <name>soccer_field_updated</name>\
                     </script>\
                  </material>\
                </visual>\
              </link>\
        </model>\
      </sdf>";

     soccerFieldSDF.SetFromString(soccerField);
     sdf::ElementPtr model = soccerFieldSDF.root->GetElement("model");
     model->GetAttribute("name")->SetFromString(fieldName);
     world->InsertModelSDF(soccerFieldSDF);
}
```

Thanks for the help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6565/reload-material-script/) by [Herve Ludmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/885/herve-ludmann/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2014-07-07**:
Can you try publishing just a [visual message](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f94ff2cefa24428ad453378d867d37013c013954/gazebo/msgs/visual.proto) to the `~/visual` topic with these fields filled in: name, parent name, and material, and see if that works? There is some sample code in the [constructor of the BoxMaker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f94ff2cefa24428ad453378d867d37013c013954/gazebo/gui/BoxMaker.cc?at=default) to show how to construct and publish a visual msg.

**Comment by [Herve Ludmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/885/herve-ludmann/) on 2014-07-15**:
I didn't saw the comment earlier, sorry ! But I also tried that in a model plugin but I had the same problem, the .material script was still not up to date.

**Comment by [Herve Ludmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/885/herve-ludmann/) on 2014-07-28**:
I tried the visual message, it works only if I create everytime a new picture and if the material file contains a list of materials (up1, up2, up3....) using the newly created image (up1.png, up2.png....).

But it is not reliable because I get a std::bad _alloc error after around 200 updates. I tried to delete the materials&textures using OGRE but I still have this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody, I manage to find a way to perfectly display the trajectory of a robot using :

- a world plugin which creates a new model (where you specify the size of your field) with a material called "trajectory"
- a "trajectory.material" file without a texture specified
- a visual plugin that uses the "createManual" function of OGRE and reuses the "trajectory" material to dynamically display the trajectory

I was not able to create a material using OGRE, that's why a reuses the "trajectory" material. The only thing required to do here is to include the world plugin into your world !

I suppressed some code lines I used for my project, so there might be a few mistakes (I don't have gazebo anymore to compile & run it).

[Download here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67028586/Trajectory.zip)

---

Originally posted by [Herve Ludmann](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/885/herve-ludmann/) with karma: 36 on 2014-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kpykc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/563/kpykc/) on 2014-10-07**:
Hi, thanks for sharing your code. BTW you may be need to mark this as answer for your question.